# Best way to allow users to manage large amount of DB rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have two large tables, as follows:

First Table:

- tbl_properties

  - id
  - address
  - city
  - state
  - zip
  - timestamp

Second Table:

- tbl_units

  - id
  - propertyID (relates the unit to a property)
  - unitName
  - timestamp

Basically I'm trying to discover the best way to manage this (sometimes huge) list of properties and units - at the user level.  That includes things like:

1. Initial upload of many properties and units (I'm imagining the user could copy and paste from Excel, for example... but I can't figure out how I would parse the information correctly on the back end).
2. Bulk editing of properties/units.
3. Bulk adding or deleting units to a certain property.

Any ideas out there?  Number 1 is the biggest question I have...

Comment: Sounds more like a question for http://ux.stackexchange.com then a technical question...

Answer (score 1):

To let users upload many properties at a time you could use `csv` files.
You would have to define a structure for the csv file that all users must follow.
Then you can let users upload files through a `file` input field and then parse them using [`fgetcsv()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) and update your database with this information. A small example:

```
// handle_upload.php
if (isset($_FILES['propfile']) && $_FILES['propfile']['error'] == 0) {
   // try to open the csv file
   $fp = fopen($_FILES['propfile']['tmp_name'], "r");
   if ($fp) {
      // you must decide if you need the headers in the csv file
      // in this example there are no header so we just loop through
      // the data
      while ($record = fgetcsv($fp)) {
        // $record[0] to $record[5] should
        // contain the data you need to insert into your table
      }
      fclose($fp);
   }
}
// do something similar for the next file containing data
// for the tbl_units table
```

Answer (score 1):

For delete you could possibly do the bulk delete by the use of the "IN" keyword in this manner for example the tbl_properties table:

```
DELETE FROM tbl_properties WHERE id IN (1,2,3...)
```

The in keyword is the same like you say this statement as:

```
DELETE FROM tbl_properties WHERE id = 1 OR id = 2 OR id = 3
```

And as how many id you want the good thing about this is that you will throw the delete statement only once to delete all those rows instead of looping on them and keep on calling the delete statement that would be a lot of work to process for the server, unfortunately for the update it's not possible cause you could only throw one where condition for each statement none the less if your going to update all the columns just with the same information for each row they have.

For parsing your excel there are libraries that could help you manage it and convert each column as an array during the parsing for you to manage it easily.